# How do I reassemble this generic airbrush based on the pictured parts?

Tags: maintenance, airbrush

Someone, trying to be helpful, dismantled a number airbrush so that the could be cleaned.

The didn't take any notes on how the parts came apart and panicked when it came time to put them back together. Which made things worse.

I believe that part A goes into the base of the airbrush where the air hose is attached, part C goes in next, the way up shown on the picture, and them part B is screwed in afterward to hold them both in. I don't know where part D goes in, it seem too large even to be part of the airbrush, but it must have come from somewhere.

[image]

Every airbrush of this type that we have was dismantled, so I have no examples to go on, and I don't want to dismantle one of the more expensive ones in case I can't get it back together.

All of the parts appear to be part of the main air inlet valve

Comment: There are 3 O-rings in the manual that *might* be your part D: 6 & 7 on the left side look most promising from what I can see. There are also parts 33 at the center bottom and 26 at the center, but as you mentioned, it looks too big to fit there.

Comment: It's too big to fit inside the valve body (pos 27), so I don't think that it belongs there.

Comment: Could it be part of the air hose then instead of part of the actual air brush?

Comment: It was from a quick release.

Comment: Spring looks like it could be part of the needle assembly. Hard to tell when many of the parts that go together appear to be missing (not shown.)